# Facebook "locale" attribute not given by Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to extract an user locale from Facebook via Facebook Graph Api.

https://graph.facebook.com/marcusmaiaa

For example, this URL request returns me a locale:

```
{
   "id": "100000879345465",
   "first_name": "Marcus",
   "gender": "male",
   "last_name": "Maia",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/marcusmaiaa",
   "locale": "pt_BR",
   "name": "Marcus Maia",
   "username": "marcusmaiaa"
}
```

But... when i try do to this same request via Facebook Graph API (**using the Graph API Explorer with an app access token**), it doesn't give me a locale:

```
{
  "id": "100000879345465", 
  "first_name": "Marcus", 
  "last_name": "Maia", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/874412045931432/", 
  "name": "Marcus Maia", 
  "updated_time": "2014-10-25T20:56:05+0000"
}
```

Why? I didn't found anything about it in the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Ask for the locale field

Comment: FYI, the `username` field has been removed in API v2.x, so from April 30th, 2015 you will not be able to query for user information using that identifier any more.

Comment: `<user_id>?fields=locale` isn't returning the locale, just the user id.